# How can I handle split view in Android SDK

Tags: android

How to split the screen into two. And making left screen constant. How to navigate to the screen which is on the right side! The expected result attached to the mail have a look @ image and can any one let me know how to approach these kind of requirement.

I already got the split using fragments. Now the problem is. I've to make left side view constant and have to navigate to the right side screen.  If anyone know about these kind of functionality. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using adobe air? if so, then you simply place a splitViewNavigator component in the main mxml view file. Then you can specify which other mxml views to show within each side of the splitView. Perhaps the following code may help?

```
s:SplitViewNavigator width="100%" height="100%" id="splitViewNavigator" autoHideFirstViewNavigator="true"> 
        <s:ViewNavigator id="leftSide" firstView="views.MasterView" width="300" height="100%"/> 
        <s:ViewNavigator id="rightSide" firstView="views.DetailView" width="100%" height="100%">
```

As for havig them interact with each other, you would use navigator.pushView or along those lines.
Let me know if im following your question correctly.